# LiteDB in .net MAUI: a proper way to organize LiteDatabase's life cycle

Tags: maui, litedb

I use sqlite in my .net maui app, but now I decided to migrate it to LiteDb since I feel like no-sql type of db better serves my app needs. In my app I used singelton wrapper around `SQLiteAsyncConnection`. With LiteDb I noticed [in their doc](https://www.litedb.org/docs/getting-started/) `LiteDatabase` as a core object handling connection to the db is intstantiated and disposed immediately

```
using(var db = new LiteDatabase(@"C:\Temp\MyData.db"))
{
   ...
}
```

also found [more examples](https://github.com/dhindrik/LiteDbDemo/blob/main/LiteDbDemo/DataService.cs) of handling it the same way. Those examples are more like demo projects though, was not able to find a real project.

I wonder won't it make too much overhead of handling connection this way, instigating and disposing it on demand, rather than having a singleton wrapping the `LiteDatabase`? My app constantly reads data from the local db, with pretty much every click, sometimes writes.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/mbdavid/LiteDB/issues/1728 ?

Comment: kindof related, but see no clear answer too. I'm not sure if "keeping the file locked indefinitely" is an issue in a single-user .net maui app, probably not. The only scenario I need to be confident is when the app crashes, so the lock is automatically released with the crash, and on the next run app does not get problem connecting to the same db. I decided to give it a try and implement IDisposable singelton